# Why is this text running outside of the li element?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Hope somebody can see what's going on with this, it's got me beat.

I have an issue with the  tag text elements inside a drop-down menu extending beyond the li element for the mobile version of the navigation in the footer. The li element has a width restriction (is shaded orange to see clearly), you can see the problem on this page when browser is mobile width wide https://www.mcveaghfleming.co.nz/nav-issues.html There are some long link names and instead of flowing under the line above they are extending past the end of the li element.

[image]

Here's the relevent html

```
<div class="footer">
<div class="blockfooter">

    <div class="row ft-low-nav ">            


        <style>
            .foot-mobile-on .dropdown-menu li{float:left; width:100%; background:orange; word-wrap: break-word !important;}
            .foot-mobile-on .dropdown-menu li,
            .foot-mobile-on .dropdown-menu li a{display:inline-block;}

        </style>

        <span class="foot-mobile-on">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse dropdown">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >


                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle make-b" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Business &amp; Corporate <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="make-b"><a href="/business-and-corporate">Business &amp; Corporate</a> </li>
                                <li><a href="#link">Anti-Money Laundering and Countering Financing of Terrorism Act 2009 Compliance and Advice</a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>



                    </ul>

                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>

        </span>
        <!-- end-->

    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--end-->
```

Comment: I'm afraid there's not enough code in your question to replicate this issue -- there should be some nearby part of your code that sets a fixed width (which the text is overflowing). Can you please ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- if unsure on the exact problematic area, it's always better to add too *much* code, rather than too little ;)

Comment: Also, what browser are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set `position:relative` or anything different than the static default to the UL.
Adding up, this is to prevent the 100% width to be referring to an upper parent. My guess is that a lack of position declaration on the parent is scaling up the DOM to the entire body width. A quick inspect on the code should give you a hint about this, but is hard without seeing the actual code in action.